# Converting DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern to Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, datetimeformatinfo

I have a validator extending from `BaseValidator` that is scattered throughout the code.  I feed in a regular expression string which is then used for server-side and client-side validation.  When used for date fields, this string currently uses the same format across all cultures, but I would like to make use of the short date pattern found in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`.  Is there something built-in for converting a date pattern to a regular expression?  Most of the other answers on Stack Overflow say to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`, but I'd be impressed if that would work for client-side validation.

Yes, we could use some sort of Datetime picker, but the product owner won't approve of that any time soon.

Comment: what do you mean when you say `I'd be impressed if that would work for client-side vlaidation..?` have you tried it.. DateTime.TryParseExact is a function that should work client side

Comment: @MethodMan DateTime is a C# object.  Is there an equivalent JavaScript object?

Comment: `Date()` for example in java you should be able to do similar in .net 
`Jave syntax for date would be Date myDate = new Date()` perhaps you can look at this for some deeper examples http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm